# Как разрешить всем пользователям доступ к папке linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cmd

Как разрешить всем пользователям доступ к папке linux?
Хочу положить файл через pscp.exe
pscp: unable to open /usr/local/bin/bot/bot.py: permission denied
Как дать доступ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/bot/
```

если есть подкаталоги, то указать флаг рекурсивной расстановки прав

```
chmod -R 777 /usr/local/bin/bot/
```

Comment: +x, на все каталоги выше должно быть еще